# crop variant with aspect ratio 1:1 don't generate square image using fluid viewhelper

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I have defined two crop variants “default” and “isotope”. The “default” contains some basic aspect rations like 1:1, 3:4, 16:9 and so on. The “isotope” variant only contains one aspect ratio 1:1, which is also defined as default (selectedRatio = 1:1). In my case, this definition is done by PageTS, which looks like this:

```
TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.crop.config.cropVariants {
    default {
        title = Default desktop
        selectedRatio = NaN
        allowedAspectRatios {
            NaN {
                title = Frei
                value = 0.0
            }
            1:1 {
                title = 1:1
                value = 1.0
            }
            3:2 {
                title = 3:2
                value = 1.5
            }
            2:3 {
                title = 2:3
                value = 0.6666666667
            }
            4:3 {
                title = 4:3
                value = 1.3333333333
            }
            3:4 {
                title = 3:4
                value = 0.75
            }
            16:9 {
                title = 16:9
                value = 1.7777777778
            }
        }
    }
    isotope {
        title = Auswahl für Isotope Plugin
        selectedRatio = 1:1
        allowedAspectRatios {
            1:1 {
                title = 1:1
                value = 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding this piece of code, the variants appears in all places, where file references can be defined, like inside e.g. news records (from news extension).

Now, after adding an image to a news record and clicking on the image manipulation button, I can select the new defined “isotope” crop variant and choose the desired 1:1 (square) crop area. So far so good.

My problem is now, that I don’t get the right output, when using this crop variant inside my fluid template using the the standard image viewhelper from TYPO3.

This:

```
<f:image image="{image}" cropVariant="isotope" maxWidth="400" />
```

don't generates square images, which I would expect.

If the **source** image has an aspect ratio of 4:3, I get flat-pressed rectangles, if the **source** image has an aspect ratio of 3:4, I get sky scrapers.

I also tried every possible combination of min/max/width/height attributes with/without additional "c", with no luck.
Sometime the result looks better for 4:3 **source** images, sometime for 3:4 images.
But I could no found a solution to get square (cropped) images for **all** kind of **aspect ratios**

[EDIT 04.07.2017]

Further experiments show different behaviors with different types of source image formats.
If the images are jpgs, I **must** set width="400c" and height="400c" to get square images. If the source images are pngs, a simple maxWidth="400" together with the cropVariant="isotope" do the job. Gif-Images seems to follow there own laws, which I have not yet looked through.

[EDIT 08.07.2017]

My current experience, after building an [extension to test hundred of possible combinations](https://github.com/mediaessenz/cropcheck): gif cropping is currently not working like expected.
To make things worse, the generated gif images are displayed differently in different browsers.
An example is this generated image:
[View this image in FF, Chrome, Safari to see the different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z87lg.gif)

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no problem at all within your code, are you sure that image cropping works? Check the image related tests in the install tool to make sure, that the server can handle image manipulation.

Comment: The install tool shows all green and image manipulation is working in general. Images are generated, but partly distort.

Comment: Did you go into the image editor and saved the image one time with the new crop variant? I think that was necessary for me.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar issues in TYPO3 7.6, the "c" parameter suddenly has no effect when used from fluid in an extbase template. Images are being squashed instead of cropped. I don't think there is a test in the install tool for the cropping. But I tried `gm convert -size 100x100 source.jpg -crop 100x100 target.jpg` on the command line, that should do as a test for cropscale, and it worked. So what I'm asking myself atm is if maybe cropping in TYPO3 is suddenly broken? Which library are you using, im or gm?

Comment: Nope I had a syntax error. had to set `height: '300c-35'` instead of `height: 300c-35` Still, the above command to test gm might be helpful

Comment: @SvenWappler I tried this, but it did not make any different. And if this should be necessary, what's the worth of the selectedRatio parameter?

Comment: @Urs I do not understand the need of height and width with additional "c" parameter at all. I used the cropVariant feature, where it should be enough to set the maxWidth, as fare I understand it. 

I use gm with this settings:

'GFX' => [
        'gdlib_png' => true,
        'jpg_quality' => '85',
        'processor' => 'GraphicsMagick',
        'processor_effects' => -1,
    ],

Comment: @alexander-grein Sorry, I was just referring to my own issue, which was due to faulty syntax. I'm not familiar with the cropVariants approach yet

Comment: does it also work for PNGs if you set `400c` AND `cropVariant="isotope"` together? Then you have a solution for the 2 most common formats. Actually, I never trust `maxWidth`, as I've always had difficulties to understand how it works – I'd rather have a clear (eindeutig) value like "cropscale it to 400px".